# Could someone please show me where I can find Flask-Admin callbacks?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I am attempting to combine Flask-Admin and a [Flask S3 Tool Suite](http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2015/04/storing-flask-uploaded-images-and-files-on-amazon-s3/) written by someone to store images to Amazon S3 simple storage. The tool I am trying to specifically use is the `S3Saver` functionality and in the article link the user goes on to say that to incorporate this tool, I would ideally use it on a flask-admin callback.

However, I cannot find a list of Flask-Admin callbacks anywhere. I have done my homework and I have literally checked the entire docs and source code for these callbacks [Flask-Admin documentation](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) .

In `flask_admin.contrib.sqla` I found some methods that kind of resembled a callback but its not what I am looking for. I imagine that it is something close to Rails's `before_action` and `after_action`. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

By the way this is the actual quote from the article

> If you wanted to handle deleting files in the admin as well, you could (for example) use s3-saver, and hook it in to one of the Flask-Admin event callbacks

What callbacks are those?

Comment: are you referring to things like `on_model_change` or `on_model_delete` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flask-Admin Callback Functions (as far as I know)

```
after_model_change(form, model, is_created)
#Called from create_model after successful database commit.

after_model_delete(model)
#Called from delete_model after successful database commit (if it has any meaning for a store backend).


on_form_prefill(form,id) 
# Called from edit_view, if the current action is rendering the form rather than receiving client side input, after default pre-filling has been performed.

on_model_change(form,model,is_created) 
#Called from create_model and update_model in the same transaction (if it has any meaning for a store backend).

on_model_delete(model) 
# Called from delete_model in the same transaction (if it has any meaning for a store backend).
```

More info at http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/  (search for "Called from")

Comment: thanks for confirming. I thought those were the callbacks but thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation for Flask Admin events :

https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.on_form_prefill

> **on_form_prefill(form, id)** Perform additional actions to pre-fill the edit form.
>
> Called from edit_view, if the current action is rendering the form
>   rather than receiving client side input, after default pre-filling has
>   been performed.
>
> By default does nothing.
>
> You only need to override this if you have added custom fields that
>   depend on the database contents in a way that Flask-admin can’t figure
>   out by itself. Fields that were added by name of a normal column or
>   relationship should work out of the box.
>
> Parameters:    form – Form instance id – id of the object that is going
>   to be edited
>
> **on_model_change(form, model, is_created)** Perform some actions before a model is created or updated.
>
> Called from create_model and update_model in the same transaction (if
>   it has any meaning for a store backend).
>
> By default does nothing.
>
> Parameters:    form – Form used to create/update model model – Model
>   that will be created/updated is_created – Will be set to True if model
>   was created and to False if edited
>
> **on_model_delete(model)** Perform some actions before a model is deleted.
>
> Called from delete_model in the same transaction (if it has any
>   meaning for a store backend).
>
> By default do nothing.